# Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance while using react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to do a functional test for my React App, my component has a div with `data-testid="btnHeaderCategory"`, on click of the div I have to update the style of the body 
I am using react and [react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/intro) for unit testing.

I am updating the style of the body with
`document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";`

Here is my component

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Main = () => { 
    const [flag, updateFlag] = useState(false);
    const getCategory = () => {
        updateFlag(true);
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
    return(
        <div onClick={getCategory} data-testid="btnHeaderCategory">
            {flag ? <div data-testid="megaMenu" > New categories </div> : ""}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Here is my test file

```
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react';

describe("components/Main",()=>{
    let Main;

    beforeAll(()=>{
      Main = require('./Main').default;

    });
    afterAll(() => {
      cleanup();
    });
    test("Test if categories shown", async()=>{

      const { getByTestId } = render(
        <Main />
      );
      fireEvent.click(getByTestId('btnHeaderCategory'));
      const elem = getByTestId('megaMenu'));
      expect(elem).toBeInTheDocument();

    });
})
```

When I try to run the test, it breaks with the following error

*TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance*

[image]

Jest configuration

```
var baseConfig = {
   collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/**/*.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!<rootDir>/coverage/**',
    '!<rootDir>/jest.config.js',
    '!**/__tests__/**',
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 100,
      branches: 100,
      functions: 100,
      lines: 100,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  collectCoverageFrom: [baseConfig.collectCoverageFrom, '!<rootDir>/build/**'],
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'clover', 'html'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 0.5,
      branches: 0.1,
      functions: 0.1,
      lines: 0.5,
    },
  },
  projects: [
    createProject({
      displayName: 'Configuration',
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/__tests__/**/*.js'],
      testEnvironment: 'node',
    }),
    createProject({

      displayName: 'Client',
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/client/**/__tests__/**/*.js'],
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',

    }),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by providing context for `custom hook`

I am using a react custom hook in my main component, which breaks the test and the error message was wrong which got me confused.

*Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance while using react testing library*

Using `renderHook` from [react-hooks-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library) fixed the problem and my test cases are working fine now.

Here is my change

```
import GlobalProvider, { GlobalContext } from '@context/global';

const { globalState } = renderHook(() => useContext(GlobalContext));

const { getByTestId } = render(
    <GlobalProvider value={globalState}>
      <Main />
    </GlobalProvider>,
);
```

Comment: So you cannot add react hooks like useState inside that function?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and it works for me... you could simplify the test by doing:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

import Main from './Main';

describe('components/Main', () => {
  test('Test if categories shown', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Main />);

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('btnHeaderCategory'));
    expect(getByTestId('megaMenu')).toBeDefined(); //Or to be in the document
  });
});
```

Also on `Main.js` I would avoid putting `""` as children on the div, by just changing: `{flag && <div data-testid="megaMenu" > New categories </div>}`, as well as adding the null check on `document.body` -> `if (document.body) document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` ... because it could be `null`.

Comment: Not working for me maybe its some configuration issue.

Comment: Not working for me maybe its some `jest` configuration issue.